# csv response for swagger 2.0 & codegen

Tags: go, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I couldn't find specific examples of handlers somewhere that send a CSV file in response. On the project we use swagger 2.0 in JSON format and codegen. So there are several problems:

1. When I start code generation according to the specification, then codegen generates a CSVProducer like this:

   ```
   CsvProducer: runtime.ProducerFunc(func(w io.Writer, data interface{}) error {
               return errors.NotImplemented("csv producer has not yet been implemented")
           }),
   ```

   In this case, JsonProducer and JsonConsumer are generated correctly, with functions from the runtime package. For the CSV format, the same package has its own consumer and producer, but for some reason it generates them the way I presented the code above. Naturally, if I change it with my hands, then in the future, during the next generation, everything flies to the default code in the form of returning the fact that the consumer is not implemented.
2. If I nevertheless change everything with my hands as it should and try to check, then when I make a request that should return a csv file, this will return (I test in insomnia):

   ```
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY,X-USER-ID,X-SPLIT-NAME,Content-Type
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
   Content-Type: text/csv
   Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2023 10:11:11 GMT
   Content-Length: 0
   ```

   How we see, Content-Length: 0. And with this appears error:

   ```
   2023/03/14 10:11:11 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from pkg/api/middleware.LoggingMiddleware.func1.1.1 (middleware.go:122)
   2023-03-14T10:11:11.445777085Z goroutine 79 [running]:
   2023-03-14T10:11:11.445809960Z runtime/debug.Stack()
   ...
   ```

Here is the pkg/api/middleware.LoggingMiddleware function code:

```
func LoggingMiddleware(ctx *open_middleware.Context) open_middleware.Builder {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            defer func() {
                if recov := recover(); recov != nil {
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    debug.PrintStack()
                    log.
                        Error().
                        Interface("err", recov).
                        Msg(r.URL.Path)

                }
            }()

            start := time.Now()
            wrapped := wrapResponseWriter(w)

            // print body
            body := &bytes.Buffer{}
            content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
            defer r.Body.Close()
            l := len(content)
            if l > bufferLen {
                l = bufferLen
            }
            body.Write(content[:l])
            r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(content))

            h.ServeHTTP(wrapped, r)

            if wrapped.Status() != http.StatusOK && wrapped.Status() != http.StatusNoContent {
                cLogger := log.Info().
                    Int("status", wrapped.Status()).
                    Str("method", r.Method).
                    Str("path", routePath(r, ctx)).
                    Dur("duration", time.Since(start)).
                    Str("query", r.URL.RawQuery).
                    RawJSON("body", body.Bytes()).
                    Str("user", r.URL.User.String()).
                    Str("api-key", r.Header.Get("X-API-KEY")).
                    Str("user-id", r.Header.Get("X-USER-ID"))

                cLogger.Str("resp", wrapped.body.String())

                cLogger.Msg(r.URL.Path)
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Here is the handler code in swagger 2.0 json:

```
"/file": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "files"
        ],
        "operationId": "GetCSVFile",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "fileName",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "produces": [
          "text/csv"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/GetCSVFileResponse"
            },
            "headers": {
              "Content-Disposition": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Attachment; filename=example.csv"
              }
            }
          },
          "default": {
            "$ref": "#/responses/defaultResponse"
          }
        }
      }
    },

    ...

    "GetCSVFileResponse": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "binary",
      "description": "CSV file response",
      "x-go-mimetype": "text/csv",
      "x-go-fileName": "example.csv",
      "x-nullable": false
    },
```

Please tell me how to fix this. I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about this...

For the generation server I use this command:

```
sudo swagger generate server \
-f ./api/swagger.json \
-s server \
--exclude-main \
--flag-strategy=pflag \
--default-scheme=http \
--template-dir=./pkg/api/templates/ \
--target=./pkg \
-q
```

I tried to format the swagger file in different ways for the correct generation, but none of the options led to the correct work.

wrapResponseWriter:

```
func wrapResponseWriter(w http.ResponseWriter) *responseWriter {
    return &responseWriter{ResponseWriter: w}
}
```

Comment: Can you share `wrapResponseWriter` function ?